# Find the value of θ if $\sinθ° = \cos(θ+40)°$

Tags: trigonometry

This is a $1$ mark question, so I assume I may be going about it wrong or in a longer than required way. Currently I am using $\cos(t) = \sin\left(\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) - t\right) $and then using $\sin(t) - \sin(s)=2\cos\left(\frac{t+s}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{t-s}{2}\right)$. This route seems too long for a $1$ mark question.
Help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: There's no simple value for sin or cos of 40 degrees ... is that supposed to be 45 degree, perhaps?

Comment: @JimN the question definitely says 40

Comment: $\color{red}\cos (\pi/2-x)=\color{red}\cos (x+a)\implies?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very simple and even simpler if you consider that $\sin\theta=\cos(90^\circ-\theta)$, so you get
$$
\theta+40^\circ=90^\circ-\theta+k360^\circ
$$
or
$$
\theta+40^\circ=-90^\circ+\theta+k360^\circ
$$
The second equation has no solution.